# Simplifying time complexity of a function

Tags: time-complexity

Say I have a time complexity O(f(m) * n) where f(m) is not a randomized function but it will always produce a value between 0 and 1 (exclusive). Should I drop the f(m) term and conclude that my time complexity is O(n)? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is big O notation you are using. It always tells maximum time an algorithm will take or time for worst case scenario. As O(f(m)*n)  will have max value n when f(m) will have max value 1. So it can be written as O(n).